# How can I select the second last and last row from the database?

Tags: mysql, sql

When we are retrieving data from database, we use something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Names
```

However, we will get all the data inside the specific table. Since I am going to update some data to the database and want to make a comparison bewteen the last row of data in the db and the most updated data, how can I select and retrieve the last two row of the database only?

Comment: There is no guaranteed order in a table. If you want the last rows, you first have to decide the order of the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using SQL Server, you would do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Names ORDER BY Name DESC
```

Comment: sorry forget to mention, i am using Mysql database.
It should be something similar to this kind of command?

Comment: `select * from Names order by name desc limit 2`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server syntax:

```sql
SELECT TOP 2 column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name DESC;
```

Example:

If you want to retrieve the last value of the `customer_name` column from the `customers` table, you need to write the following query:

```sql
SELECT LAST (CUSTOMER_NAME) AS LAST_CUSTOMER FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include a column in the Names table to keep track of when a name was added to the table since you cannot guarantee that the rows are in the order that they were inserted. With that column you can use the order by clause..

In MySQL Syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM Names
ORDER BY order_column DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

If you want to get the last rows as they are, you cannot order the table by the inserted names because that is just getting the 2 names that come last in an alphabetically sorted list of names. You could try something like this where you include an offset in the limit clause if you get the number of rows in the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Names
LIMIT *num_rows*-2, 2;
```

You would have to know the number of rows to use this query or use an additional query to implement a row count that works with limit. This, however, still may not be accurate since the system may not order the rows as they were inserted. I still recommend the first option where you keep track of order/time a name was inserted.